# Insertar datos en tablas con REF

Tags: oracle

!Buenas!

Estoy realizando un ejercicio sobre **Objetos Relacionales** en Base de Datos. La verdad que estoy un poco perdido, y necesito insertar unos datos en una tabla que he creado de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE empleados OF Empleado(
idEmpleado PRIMARY KEY);
```

Y el **tipo** de objeto es este:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Empleado AS OBJECT(
idEmpleado NUMBER,
nombre VARCHAR(20),
apellidos VARCHAR(20),
salario NUMBER,
vencargado REF Encargado,
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION ordenarID return NUMBER,
MEMBER FUNCTION encargadoEmpleado return Encargado);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Empleado
AS
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION ordenarID return NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
RETURN idEmpleado;
END;
END;
```

Donde el atributo de `vencargado` viene de este otro tipo de objeto:

```
CREATE TYPE Encargado AS OBJECT(
idEncargado NUMBER,
nombre VARCHAR(20),
apellidos VARCHAR(20),
cargo VARCHAR(20),
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION ordenarID return NUMBER,
MEMBER FUNCTION empleadosCargo return NUMBER);
CREATE TYPE BODY Encargado
AS
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION ordenarID return NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
RETURN idEncargado;
END;
END;
```

He intentado añadir unos datos a la tabla de **empleados** y me ha ocurrido este error, y no se como introducir los valores:

> tipos de dato inconsistentes: se esperaba REF se ha obtenido NUMBER

Los he añadido de esta forma:

```
INSERT INTO empleados VALUES ( Empleado(1,'Juan','Rodriguez',1600,1));
```

Si alguien me puede orientar, seria de gran ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!Buenas!

Ya lo resolví.

El problema estaba en la creación de la tabla `Empleados` ya que no hacia referencia al objeto de `Empleado`. Para solucionarlo hay que crearlo de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE empleados OF Empleado(
idEmpleado PRIMARY KEY,
SCOPE FOR (vencargado) is encargados);
```

Y así deja insertar datos sin problemas, o al menos, a mi no he ha dado ningún problema.

Espero que sirva de referencia a otros usuarios :)